# how to delete all dependencies from package.json?

Tags: package.json

I accidentally used some command and installed all the packages in the dependencies but I want to install them in the devDepandancies can some one help me?

I accidentally used some command all went wrong need some help!!

Comment: You can uninstall those packages, then cut paste those packages in package.json from dependencies to devDependecies and then you can run npm install or yarn add